# Help identifying space-themed sets

Tags: technic, set-identification, space

I have acquired a 20 pound bag of space-themed Lego pieces that seem to belong to some special Technic set(s). Many pieces and assemblies seem way too unusual to be [image] acquired from a random bulk purchase by the prior owner - the pieces are themed and uncommon. I am attaching some photos for your reference. I would love to hear if any of you can identify which set(s) these may belong to, unless the prior owner totally made these up. Thank you for your help! I have spent about 20 years of my life around LEGO bricks and have never seen any pieces like these. I am stumped!

**P.S.** I've realized that I have a Death Star in the bag and a Captain Rex's AT-TE, but still can't figure out what the white and the yellow ones are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of observations:

- Neither of these pictures shows complete sets
- The parts you show in each picture most likely do not all come from the same set

From what I can see, you have the following parts of sets in the pictures, clockwise from top left:

1. Parts of a Y-wing (likely [9495 Gold Leader's Y-wing Starfighter](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9495-1&name=Gold%20Leader%27s%20Y-wing%20Starfighter&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%204/5/6%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) ) plus parts of [7166 Imperial Shuttle](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7166-1&name=Imperial%20Shuttle&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%204/5/6%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image][image]

2. Parts of a Naboo Starfighter (likely [7660 Naboo N-1 Starfighter and Vulture Droid](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7660-1&name=Naboo%20N-1%20Starfighter%20and%20Vulture%20Droid&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%201%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)) plus parts of another set (the large grey wedge with the green stickers is not from 7660).

[image]

3. Parts of [10188 Deathstar](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10188-1&name=Death%20Star&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%204/5/6%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) mixed with parts of a [8039 Venator-Class Republic Attack Cruiser](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8039-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image][image]

4. More parts from the Venator Class Attack Cruiser (the engines on the left), plus a [7675 AT-TE](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7675-1&name=AT-TE%20Walker&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Clone%20Wars%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I greatly appreciate it. The Star Wars themed Lego sets are definitely not my expertise! I only posted photos of the partially assembled parts as they seemed easiest to identify. The photos only show a fraction of the set, there is still over half a bag of loose individual parts. Anyways, thank you again, and happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

Top Left

[7659-1 -  Imperial Landing Craft](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7659-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D)

Top right seems to be two sets

[7930-1 - Bounty Hunter Assault Gunship](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7930-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D)

and

[7877-1 - Naboo Starfighter](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7877-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D)